# add remove value from counter using toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have made two scripts for toggling an icon:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.actions').on('click', function(event) {
        var name = $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye');
    });

    $('.actions').on('click', function(event) {
        var name = $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye-slash');
    });
});
```

This is works perfectly. I'm trying also to add/remove a value (Boolean) in a different counter I have:

```
<div class="hello-badge" data-badge="0">
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: We need more information to help you. Specifically what attribiute are you trying to change, to what value and under what event?

Comment: Hi Rory. these two scripts just toggle between two different icons (of the same button) . on my button first click i want to add + 1 to the data-badge counter. pressing the second time I want to reduce -1 from the data-badge counter.

Answer (score 0):

> on my button first click i want to add + 1 to the data-badge counter. pressing the second time I want to reduce -1 from the data-badge counter

Given the above then the value of the data attribute will only ever be `0` or `1`, assuming it starts on `0` as per your HTML example you an just toggle back and forth between those values on successive clicks.

Also note that you can join both `toggleClass` statements in to a single event handler and call. Try this:

```
$('.actions').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-eye fa-eye-slash');
    $('.hello-badge').data('badge', $('.hello-badge').data('badge') == 0 ? 1 : 0);
});
```